How to sort stacked bar graph
mockdata:




Type Apple
Month
freq




0
fuji
January
1


1
gala
February
1


2
gala
February
1


3
gala
March
1


4
opal
January
1


5
opal
April
1



See my code down below.
It produces a stacked bargraph of the type of apples sold per month (with freq simply being 1 for each row).
I would like bars in the graph to be sorted by months ascending. Starting at January.
v[['Type Apple','Month', 'freq']].groupby(['Month', 'Type Apple']).agg('count').unstack().plot.barh(stacked=True).legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0))


Please include mock data with expected graph output.

I've added the mockdata now, the stacked bargraph can't be added

Try this using @Dmitry543 creating categorical dtype, however reverse the order to graph from Jan to Dec on Y-axis.  Also, used observed=True in groupby eliminating non-seen months in groupby:
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], categories=months[::-1], ordered=True)

df[['Type Apple','Month', 'freq']].groupby(['Month', 'Type Apple'], observed=True).agg('count').unstack().plot.barh(stacked=True).legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0))

Output:


This worked for me, thank you!

to be able to order by Month, it should be added as a categorical variable.
define the order:
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

set month as a categorical type:
v['Month'] = pd.Categorical(v['Month'], categories=months, ordered=True)

